# How can I get a value from external java script file to code behind file?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I am developing a web application using .NET4.0 and C# languge. In that application I have a aspx page and corresponding java script file. I need to access the value present in the external java script file in code behind file. How can I access that? I linked external java script and aspx page through ControlResources. Anyone please  help in this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you got so far? Also, are you trying to explicitly read a text file JavaScript file from the server? Or are you trying to retrieve a variable after post-back?

Comment: @Richard Thanks for your response. My application is stand alone one. That means autoPostBack id false. I am trying to retreive a variable simply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Hidden field on Server side and populate it on client side with your data. thus you will be able to make client end data on server side. I think its the only way of doing it.

aspx

```
<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="myhidden" />

<script>
function  setthidden()
 {
   document.getElementById('myhidden').value = "your value";// assign your value here
 }

 window.onload=setthidden;

</script>
```

on server side

```
string myhiddenvalue=myhidden.Value;
```

Comment: @User StackOverflow is a place to offer advice on existing attempts to resolve a problem; not to simply provide code. :)

Answer (score 2):

The only way JS can communicate with the server side code (at run time) is by a HTTP POST.

if you are talking about getting a constant value on the JS file the only way you have is by opening the JS file in read mode an get what you need (even if I would not suggest you to go down this road)

Answer (score 1):

Http post from the client to the server is the only way.. preferably using Ajax